# Как получить список с абсолютными путями всех каталогов и файлов в них рекурсивно?

Tags: bash

В каталоге **/home/user/files** лежит много каталогов и файлов.
В каждом каталоге, включая указанный выше, лежат файлы.
Нужно из указанного выше каталога получить список всех каталогов и вложенных в них подкаталогов, а так же файлов.
Получить в виде списка:

> /path/to/file.ext

Как я понял, мне подойдет строка:

```
find . -name "*" -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Но она выводит результат в "ls -l", а спарсить его не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы получить список файлов с абсолютными путями, укажите абсолютный путь к данному каталогу:

```
$ find /абсолютный/путь/к/каталогу -type f
```

в случае, если это текущий каталог, можно воспользоваться, например, значением переменной окружения `$PWD`:

```
$ find $PWD -type f
```

---

если же вам нужны не только файлы (как указано в приводимой вами команде), а и каталоги в том числе (как указано в заголовке вопроса), то добавьте к команде ещё `-o -type d`:

```
$ find /абсолютный/путь/к/каталогу -type f -o -type d
```

---

вообще, объекты в файловой системе не ограничиваются только (обычными) файлами (`f`) и каталогами (`d`). есть ещё и блочные (`b`) и символьные (`c`) устройства, именованные каналы (`p`), сокеты (`s`) и символические ссылки (`l`). см. `man find` про описание опции `-type`.

если вы вообще уберёте упоминания этой опции, то будут выведены все типы объектов:

```
$ find /путь
```

Comment: Спасибо! Последняя команда - то, что надо.

Comment: @kompas, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Достаточно (уже) предпоследней. И вообще мне нужны были только файлы и каталоги. =)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться параметром `-R` утилиты `ls`

```
ls -R .
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем то, что нужно.
Мне бы в формате:
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2